# Error while sending a filename as a parameter to a function module in python. How to solve?

Tags: python

```
#This code does the checking of the function input.

import re
import sys


def pyexam(file_name):
    fp = open(file_name) 
    testCaseInput = open('input.txt','r')
    testCaseOutput = open('output.txt','r')

    eval(compile(fp.read(),'prob.txt','exec'))
    if add(int(testCaseInput.read())) == int(testCaseOutput.read()):
        print "yes"
    else:
        print "no"

file_name ='prob.txt'
pyexam(file_name)
```

The file prob.txt has an add module.

This works without enclosing it in a function. Also, it works when I send the file name as the parameter. So, its very confusing as to why it is not working when I send the filename as a parameter to the function module. The error I get is this:

```
File "exam.py", line 13, in pyexam
    if add(int(testCaseInput.read())) == int(testCaseOutput.read()):
NameError: global name 'add' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you put your `add` code in a .py file, then use `add = __import__("prob").add`?

Answer (score 3):

Use *exec* instead of *eval*.

The *eval()* function is for evaluating expressions and returning (not assigning) a result:

```
>>> x = eval('3+5')
>>> x
>>> 8
```

The *exec* statement executes statements including assignments:

```
>>> exec 'y = 3 + 5'
>>> y
>>> 8
```

See http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement and http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval .

Also note that your code and my examples work with the globals() or module-level namespace.  Due to CPython fast local optimizations, local variables aren't available for writing by exec.